# nginx config file not working

Tags: javascript, html, nginx

I looked around at other examples and tried to replicate a very basic nginx server layout. However, it's not working at all (other than example.com, which correctly redirects to index.html).

Here's my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /draw/ {
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/projects/draw;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /drawsomething.html;
    }
    location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/pic;
    }
}
```

Basically, I store everything in `/templates/`. I want to make it so when someone goes to `example.com/draw` it displays `drawsomething.html`, which is in `/var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/projects/draw`. I followed the example on the website and it doesn't seem to be working. The redirect for images seems to be working, though. Also, what if I want to include script files? Could I just use:

```
location ~ \.js$ {
    root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/script;
}
```

Comment: @AD7six so do I just put a main root at the top and then put sub roots for each location block?

Comment: Actually I made a mistake there - there is a server root, so it's not going to break - it just looks a bit weird: what do you understand root to be doing? having urls `/foo` `/foo.gif`, `/foo.js` going to different places is _probably_ going to get quite confusing.

Comment: @AD7six basically, for now I want everything under `/template`. Main files like `index.html` will be in this directory. Inside of template, I'll have `/pic`, `/projects`, and `/script` (going to move script later). So, `example.com/draw` should get draw something.html, which is inside of `templates/projects/draw/`. The script/image files will be about the same, except in their respective directories.

Comment: what you describe is not IMO "a very basic nginx server layout". "a very basic nginx server layout" is defining the root and that's about it (i.e. urls map to file paths directly) :). Anyway what is "example on the website" in what way "doesn't seem to be working". You'll do well to [enable debug logging](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) and I find it helps to put `add_header section "something unique";` into each location block - you can tell what happened for each request from http headers then. Edit the question with info - don't add more comments.

Comment: What is a sample URL for a js file and an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my nginx config with the following setup. I ended up just using node.js's proxy system by redirecting all traffic to port 15301, the port on which node.js was listening.

```
http {
    server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/royhowie.com/public_html/;
        index index.html;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:15301/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```